# How to deleted record as false in SQL Server from winforms UI using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem to set deleted record as false in my SQL Server.I tried a lot.

My problem is i have a table in some Of the columns id,name etc...id as primary
  key constraint. When the user delete the record? so that record should be 
  present on the table. i will make that record as false in my table?

In future he want to add the record with the deleted id? we give the chance to
  add a record with that id?

plz tell me the example of doing this? i tried a lot but i don't know. because
  primary key doesn't accept duplicates so i strucked here.

My delete stored procedure:

If user press the delete button in my UI:

This stored procedure is execute in my back-end:

```
update table set id=id*-1, flag=1 where id=@id and flag=0;
```

In front i have shown record is deleted.

But if he want to add the record with that deleted id. Primary key voilation
  error from my database.when he insert the record.

Thanks

Comment: `I tried a lot` - what did you try?

Comment: For deleting a record

Comment: Please post the code which you "tried" so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a column `DeleteFlag bit` into the table, set to false by default.
2. Always add the where condition `WHERE DeleteFlag = 0` to display data in UI
3. Update the column to true if user "delete" the record from UI

Do not alter primary key, they are not intended to change.

**EDIT**

To reuse the deleted `Id`, you can negate the `Id` and mark the record as deleted. However, this is not recommended to update the primary key in normal case.

example

```
UPDATE id = -1 * id, flag = 1 WHERE id = @id and flag = 0;
```

**EDIT 2**

Missed if the use delete the new record with same deleted id, just negate the id is not enough.

```
UPDATE t SET id = newId.Value, flag = 1, new_field=@id     
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(Id) >= 0 THEN -1 ELSE MIN(Id) - 1 END AS value 
    FROM table with(updlock)
) AS newId
WHERE t.id = @id AND flag = 0
```

Comment: @Eric.i tried this one previously..but primary key doesn't accept the same id for add a record.

Comment: @Nag How does the primary key generated? Is there any reason not use identity?

Comment: I have generated primary key for the ward id's.These id's are unique.No i won't use any identity here.

Comment: @Nag If you need to reuse the deleted id, what do you expect when the record undo delete?

Comment: No dont't undo that deleted record.that record should be present In database.In future he will see that old data..But i will give chance to add new data with that deleted id how can i?do this?

Comment: @Nag A simple way is to mark delete and negates the id. IMHO, it is not a standard way to do so.

Comment: how to negate the particular id?

Comment: can any other procedure for this type of problem?some thing like take an another id like that.

Comment: There is a problem if the user delete the record twice.Primay key voilation is came again (duplicate id in negative value)

Comment: If i add flag is set to "0" in my update statement it gives an error."Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" because duplicate key cannot inserted in primary key right? i.e, negative number. how to solve this issue?

Comment: either i.e negative or positive number in primary key column.

Comment: yeah it's working..but the ward_id will be changed totally..But the user have confusion in future which ward_id data his deleted one if he see later. he may be confused. can we get the same id after delete the record?

Comment: @Nag I am afraid you need to add a new field to store the old id

Comment: Thanks eric this works charm..i just add new field and set new field as old id in my update statement.(Delete stored procedure)

Comment: If u don't mine why not set primary key value as negative?as you said this is not recommend. why?

Comment: @Nag If you delete #20, changed to #-20. Then you add new id as #20 and delete it, it would cause collision for #-20 if you just negate the new id.

Comment: i think so edit 2 is working fine..If there any problem in edit 2 can u tell me?

Comment: Thanks eric for your effort